# Ruby upload file error

Tags: ruby, upload, amazon-s3, temporary-files

I am trying to create a form that will upload files to AWS S3. I have searched all around for an answer but I am getting the error "TypeError at /upload can't convert Symbol into Integer"

Here is the block of code

```
    post '/upload' do
    s3 = AWS::S3.new(
  :access_key_id => 'X',
  :secret_access_key => 'X')
    bucket = s3.buckets['X']

    title = params['title']
    desc = params['desc']
    file = params['file'][:tempfile]

    s3.buckets['indio'].objects[title].write(:file => file)
end
```

I get the error on the line

```
file = params['file'][:tempfile]
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically the error `can't convert Symbol into Integer` hints to the fact that you are trying to access an array with a non-integer.

From this I suspect the `params['file']` is an array or a string, and not whatever you think it is.

Find out exactly what you got in `params['file']` and continue from there.

Comment: Alright. I changed it to file - params['file'] and now I am getting the error "Errno::ENOENT at /upload No such file or directory". Does this mean it cannot find the file that I am uploading?

Comment: @user3809951 - what's the value of `params['file']`? is it a location on the _client_ machine? did you actually _upload_ the file?

Comment: The value is just the file name, not the path. params['file'] = "songname.mp3"

Comment: @user3809951 - is this file available on the _server_? if not you need to _upload_ it - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-file-uploading.htm

Comment: Thanks for that link. I found my problem!